# React and Mongo: Loading multiple object state arrays based on condition

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

this is my first time posting a question here so please let me know if I am missing something.  I am trying to load three different object arrays based on the booleans started and complete.

The issue I am running into is that even though each returned task is entering the correct condition, the value is overwritten each time if there is more than one task that is completed, started, etc.  I figured this is likely a closure issue but so far none of my attempts at fixing it have worked.  I'd really appreciate some input.

```
    const[started, setStarted] = useState([{
        title: String,
        description: String,
        date: Object,
        username: String,
        complete: Boolean,
        started:Boolean,
        workers: Array,
        teamID: Number,
        team: String
    }])

    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([{
        title: String,
        description: String,
        date: Object,
        username: String,
        complete: Boolean,
        started:Boolean,
        workers: Array,
        teamID: Number,
        team: String
    }])

    const [completes, setCompletes] = useState([{
        title: String,
        description: String,
        date: Object,
        username: String,
        complete: Boolean,
        started:Boolean,
        workers: Array,
        teamID: Number,
        team: String
    }])

    useEffect( () => {
        const team = localStorage.getItem('team');
        console.log(team);
        axios.get(`/teamTasks/${team}`)
        .then(res => {
            const tasksGrabed = res.data;
            console.log(tasksGrabed);
            loadTasks(tasksGrabed);
        })
    },[])

    function loadTasks(tasksGrabed) {
        var i;
        var task;
        setCompletes([])
        setStarted([])
        setTodos([])

        for (i=0;i<tasksGrabed.length;i++) {
            task=tasksGrabed[i];
            if (task.complete === true) {
                setCompletes([task,...completes]);
                console.log(task.title + " complete");
                console.log(completes);
            } else if (task.started === true) {
                setStarted([task,...started]);
                console.log(task.title + " started");
            } else {
                setTodos([task,...todos]);
                console.log(task.title + " todos");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with your states initialisation. Are you trying to type your state objects? If you are, you should look how to type your variables when using useState because it doesn't look like it is the right way. Also the way you are spreading is where you would want to look to debug. Google is your best friend in this scenario! Happy coding. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to update the state this way with a for loop because it does not updates immediately, take a look [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), however you can use [the previous value](https://blog.logrocket.com/accessing-previous-props-state-react-hooks/) of the `useState` hook before the component rerenders and update based on it, but lets make it simple for now :

```js
const loadTasks = (tasksGrabed) => {
  let completes = [];
  let started = [];
  let todos = [];

  tasksGrabed.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.complete === true) {
      completes.push(element);
    } else if (element.started === true) {
      started.push(element);
    } else {
      todos.push(element);
    }
  });

  // once you update your arrays with the corresponding objects,  you update your state
  setCompletes(completes);
  setStarted(started);
  setTodos(todos);
};
```